# How do I bulk rename my .json files using a name value inside each JSON file?

Tags: python, json, rename, file-rename

O have a folder with 1,800 json files. I need to bulk rename all 1800 files with a key-value pair that is unique for each of the JSON files. For example each JSON has this stored inside it and is originally named "03801f63a9bf54d2c7b30a7d121c6359-asset.json",

```
{
"asset": {
    "format": "PNG",
    "id": "03801f63a9bf54d2c7b30a7d121c6359",
    "name": "IMG_2133.PNG",
    "path": "file:/home/kai/JSON2YOLO/training-images/imagess/IMG_2133.PNG",
    "size": {
        "width": 1920,
        "height": 1080
    },
    "state": 2,
    "type": 1
},
"regions": [
    {
        "id": "SLrFhEAR0",
        "type": "RECTANGLE",
        "tags": [
            "X"
        ],
        "boundingBox": {
            "height": 653.9723502304148,
            "width": 645.9720062208398,
            "left": 1071.9751166407466,
            "top": 99.53917050691241
        },
        "points": [
            {
                "x": 1071.9751166407466,
                "y": 99.53917050691241
            },
            {
                "x": 1717.9471228615864,
                "y": 99.53917050691241
            },
            {
                "x": 1717.9471228615864,
                "y": 753.5115207373271
            },
            {
                "x": 1071.9751166407466,
                "y": 753.5115207373271
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "SEEt8pqnV",
        "type": "RECTANGLE",
        "tags": [
            "Y"
        ],
        "boundingBox": {
            "height": 421.7972350230415,
            "width": 576.049766718507,
            "left": 17.671073094867808,
            "top": 89.13810483870968
        },
        "points": [
            {
                "x": 17.671073094867808,
                "y": 89.13810483870968
            },
            {
                "x": 593.7208398133748,
                "y": 89.13810483870968
            },
            {
                "x": 593.7208398133748,
                "y": 510.9353398617512
            },
            {
                "x": 17.671073094867808,
                "y": 510.9353398617512
            }
        ]
    }
],
"version": "2.2.0" }
```

need to basically rename the file name from "03801f63a9bf54d2c7b30a7d121c6359-asset.json" to "IMG_2133" with the JSON extension of `.json` so that the file name ends up as "IMG_2133.json". I need to be able to take in all 1800 json files and rename them with their name values.

Answer (score 1):

So you should enumerate through all the files in your directory. Open them using the json library read their name from the json and then rename the file to that.

Here is something I put together quickly. I don't guarantee that this will work but it should give you the general idea.

```
import os
import json
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

files = [f for f in listdir(os.getcwd()) if isfile(join(os.getcwd(), f))]

for f in files:
  if f.endswith('.json'):
    openFile=open(f,"r")
    fileData = json.load(openFile)
    oldName = fileData['asset']['name']
    newName = oldName.replace('.PNG', '.json')
    os.rename(f,newName)
    print("Renamed "+ oldName + " to " + newName)
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because in the json file, there is an format value containing "PNG", so maybe the  old files names don't always end by ".PNG"

Comment: Yeah you right. But it can be fixed by changing this line `newName = oldName.replace('.PNG', '.json')` to `newName = oldName.replace('.'+fileData['asset']['format'], '.json')`

Answer (score 0):

this should work under 3 conditions:

-you are on windows (because the i used a "/" in my paths)

-all new files names are differents (for obvious reasons)

-and the new files names don't contains the dot character (if some names contains a
dot, tell me i can modify the script to handle those cases)

```
import json                                                         # this module is used to read json files
import os                                                           # this modules is used to get all the names of your json files and rename them

folder_path = "test_folder"                                         # you specifie the folder conatining your json files

files = os.listdir(folder_path)                                     # you all the files names in the specified folder

for file in files:                                                  # for each file in the folder
    with open(f"{folder_path}/{file}", "r") as f:                   # you open the file
        json_file = json.load(f)                                    # you get the infos stored in the json file as a dictionary
    filename = json_file["asset"]["name"].split(".")[0] + ".json"   # you generate the new filename from the dictionary
    os.rename(f"{folder_path}/{file}", f"{folder_path}/{filename}") # you rename the file
```

you just need to put the path of the folder where your files are in the folder_path variable (line 4)

I hope this was helpful